# Conditional grouping/ loops for 2 vectors

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, finance

Suppose an investment gives $80 coupon semiannually i.e. $40 every six months. Six months, 12 month and 18 month interest rates are 3.4%, 4.9% and 5.2% respectively.
I need to discount them to present value. Mathematically, I would do

```
40*EXP((-.034)*(.5))+40*EXP((-.049)*(1))+40*EXP((-.052%)*(1.5))
```

or

```
K*EXP((r1)*(t1))+K*EXP((-r2)*(t2))+K*EXP((-r3)*(t3))
```

1) Now if payout wasn't semiannually, say it was monthly i.e every month or quarterly i.e every quarter, how do i code so that in case of monthly payout

```
K*EXP((r1)*(1/12))+K*EXP((-r2)*(1/6))+K*EXP((-r3)*(1/4))+ ....
```

or in case of quarterly it needs to skip every 2 variable in t

```
K*EXP((-r1)*(1/4))+K*EXP((-r2)*(1/2))+K* EXP((-r3)*(3/4))
```

2) After the time runs for a year- how can i run a loop to just add 1 and then skip the same number of variable

```
t<- c(1/12,1/6,1/4,1/3,5/12,1/2,7/12,2/3,3/4,5/6,11/12,1)
j<- t+1
```

do i define another variable like j and keep doing it

Help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: `r<- range(c(1%,12%))` is not valid R code.

Comment: Yes, please clarify your question, as it's not clear what you're trying to do.    FYI, if you want to see all the combinations of those, here's a way: `t <- 1:12/12;
r <- 1:12/100;
combo <- expand.grid(t, r);
combo$product = combo$Var1 * combo$Var2`

Comment: Sorry guys- I am very new with R. I will try to rephrase it

Answer (score 0):

Please see the algorithm below for vector subsetting and multiplication, as well as `for`-loop.

N.B. you should not use percent notation with `%`, like `1%`, use `0.01` instead.

```
t <- c(1 / 12, 1 / 6, 1 / 4, 1 / 3, 5 / 12, 1 / 2, 7 / 12, 2 / 3, 3 / 4, 5 / 6, 11 / 12, 1)
r <- range(c(1, 12) / 100)

# 1.) Pick any one or few selective values from t and multiply with all/any value in r.
# the first and the second elements of vector multiplied by all r elements
t[1:2] * r
# [1] 0.0008333333 0.0200000000

# 2.) Can I run a loop where 't' time goes beyond 1 year?
i <- 2 # number of years
total <- numeric(0)
for(i in 2:(i + 1)) {
  total <- c(total, t * i)
}

# t for 2 years
total  
# [1] 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.8333333 1.0000000 1.1666667 1.3333333 1.5000000 1.6666667 1.8333333
# [12] 2.0000000 0.2500000 0.5000000 0.7500000 1.0000000 1.2500000 1.5000000 1.7500000 2.0000000 2.2500000 2.5000000
#
```